# How to apply count up function to multiple values on the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have dynamically generated values inside a table. Each of those values contains an int (number in seconds).

Now I want to count them up

```js
function startCount() {
  var time = $(".count").text();

  setInterval(function() {
    ++time;
  }, 1000);

  $(".count").text(time);
}
```

```html
<div class="count">270219</div>
<div class="count">265454</div>
<div class="count">312565</div>
<div class="count">254587</div>
```

However, when I do that, it concatenates all the values, instead of counting them up individually.

If I use "Id" instead of "class" it picks just the first value, without taking care of the others.

The `startCount()` is fired in my Ajax complete function.

What can I do?

Comment: parse the `time` to Number... `.text()` returns a string, thats why it concatenates

Comment: Use `parseInt(val)` and then add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the individual `.count` nodes and set the new text for each of them.

- You can use jquery's [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function to loop over the individual elements
- then use [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to convert the text of the `.count` nodes to a number

Example:

```js
function startCount() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".count").each(function() {
      let el = $(this);
      let time = Number(el.text()) + 1;
      el.text(time);
    });
  }, 1000);
}

startCount();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count">270219</div>
<div class="count">265454</div>
<div class="count">312565</div>
<div class="count">254587</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. I thought I'd just copy-paste and see what happens. It's working flawlessly!

Comment: You can also win some times by avoiding to create 2 `let` for every row by doing everything into a single line:  `this.innerHTML = Number(this.innerHTML) + 1;` (And also removing jQuery functions)

Comment: No need for the each

Comment: @mplungjan the each is needed because there are multiple elements (with independent count values)
@Arthur true, you could do it without jquery, though i would use `textContent` in this case

Comment: @mplungjan, I think yes.. The jquery `.text()` function you use will do a `each` for you.. So for me, the best is understandable code, and seeing a `setTimeout/each` in a small function like this will make you understand way better the function's goal.

Comment: I use jQuery when I need it. Why the obsession with "quitting jQuery" as if it was a drug? I use querySelector and fetch more and more, but if someone here use jQuery I see no problem

Answer (score 2):

Without the .each

```js
function startCount() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".count").text(function() {
      var val = +$(this).text();
      return ++val;
    })
  }, 1000);
}
startCount()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count">270219</div>
<div class="count">265454</div>
<div class="count">312565</div>
<div class="count">254587</div>
```

Easier to read

```js
function startCount() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".count").text(function() {
      var val = +$(this).data("secs");
      $(this).data("secs",++val);
      return new Date(val * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
    })
  }, 1000);
}
startCount()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count" data-secs="270219"></div>
<div class="count" data-secs="265454"></div>
<div class="count" data-secs="312565"></div>
<div class="count" data-secs="254587"></div>
```

Comment: This answer is good and do not need to be downvoted. It just bring a heavier method, not a prettier.

Comment: When I said prettier, I meant hours, minutes and seconds instead of seconds

Comment: @mplungjan noice

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) on the elements that you've got from the selector, [`unary operator(+)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) to convert the string to number:

```js
function startCount() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".count").each(function(idx, element) {
      var time = +$(this).text();
      $(element).html(++time);
    });
  }, 1000);
}
startCount();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count">270219</div>
<div class="count">265454</div>
<div class="count">312565</div>
<div class="count">254587</div>
```

Comment: This is working but look at the @Turtlefight answer, he switch the `each` and `setInterval` to only have 1 function running and not N (with N number of rows), also your code is storing every value into a "unique" `time` var, who contain multiple scope. It's not the best for understanding and can bring error on future updates

Comment: @Arthur you're right, I've updated the code(switched the setInterval and .each())

Comment: No need for the each

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party. However, you need to:

- Iterate over all `.count` elements
- Read the current value of an element as an integer
- Increment the value and set it back
- Do this using an interval

```html
<div class="count">270219</div>
<div class="count">265454</div>
<div class="count">312565</div>
<div class="count">254587</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function startCount() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $(".count").each((i, e) => {
                val = +$(e).text();
                $(e).text(++val);
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
    startCount();
</script>
```

Comment: No need for each

Answer (score 0):

This answer already have been answered but I just want to propose a ES6 solution without jQuery

```js
const startCount = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.count')).forEach(count => {
      count.textContent = Number(count.textContent) + 1;
    });
  }, 1000);
};
startCount ();
```

```html
<div class="count">270219</div>
<div class="count">265454</div>
<div class="count">312565</div>
<div class="count">254587</div>
```

---

If you do **NOT** want to update the HTML (add, remove `.count` elements) you can store the list on a variable to avoid looking the DOM every second.

```js
(() => {
  // This will be only one time
  const counts = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.count'));
  setInterval(() => {
    // Will be executed every seconds
    counts.forEach(count => {
      count.textContent = Number(count.textContent) + 1;
    });
  }, 1000);
})();
```

```html
<div class="count">270219</div>
<div class="count">265454</div>
<div class="count">312565</div>
<div class="count">254587</div>
```